# Odd Chrome Crashes

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash

Chrome has become nearly unusable due to frequent crashes.

The following behaviour:

Crashes.

I get a crash report that is not informative to the likes of me.

Click restart.

Window with a single tab will opens, but there is a 16 second long pause.  Eventually I get the "Aw Snap" error message.

Click reload.  Loads instantly.

Click History, reopen window of 9 tabs.

At this point I will be stable for a time period ranging from minutes to hours.  At some point the window gets sluggish, then will crash.

I currently have all extensions disabled.

Latest trial:  All plugins disabled.
Chrome PDF Viewer
Adobe Flash Player 24.0 r0
Native Client 
Widevine Content Decryption Module 1.4.8.903

I know what the first 2 do.  2nd pair???

Since disabling hasn't crashed.
Chrome offline editing (google sheets and docs) disabled.

I downloaded and reinstalled Chrome from Google's site.

What do I try next?

Head of crash report:

```
Process:               Google Chrome [80267]
Path:                  /Applications/Web/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Identifier:            com.google.Chrome
Version:               55.0.2883.95 (2883.95)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Google Chrome [80267]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2017-01-20 09:21:08.719 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1912)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D841BE19-D6E1-08BE-285B-1E5BA599F56E


Time Awake Since Boot: 3100000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(itemSelected:) from sender NSMenuItem 0x6000008ae040
```

I'm running Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) under Mac Yosemite 10.10.5

Computer has 24 G of ram.  4 cores.

Firefox sometimes has inordinately long pauses, but this has been true for many releases.

Comment: Maybe try clearing your Chrome cache. How much RAM does your computer have? Does this happen on any other browsers that you have installed?

Comment: Does it happen in another user account?

Answer (score 1):

try to re(move) the 'Local State' in Terminal:

```
mv ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Local\ State ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Local\ State.old
```

It helped me.